# How to display input cells in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I ran the code to hide the cells of Jupyter notebook and it worked. Any ideas on how to display the cells again?

```
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML('''<script>
    var code_show=true; //true -> hide code at first

    function code_toggle() {
        $('div.prompt').hide(); // always hide prompt

        if (code_show){
            $('div.input').hide();
        } else {
            $('div.input').show();
        }
        code_show = !code_show
    }
    $( document ).ready(code_toggle);
</script>
''')
```

This is what I am seeing

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Basically, if you restart Anacond and run the notebook again you see all the cells